# Dynamic Exe Parameters on Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a loop that pass through a folder for files, then the script only takes the files with the extension .wav, so I call an exe with two parameters and converts the audio. Without a loop works, because the command is a String[] variable and I just have to put my parameters in parentheses, but when I tried to make it all dynamic nothing happens, even I tried the normal static version, but the parameters in two separated strings, then I've added those strings to the String[] that contains the command to execute the application and it just doesnt' work. This is the code (With loop):

```
File dir = new File("moved");
File[] dirlist = dir.listFiles();
for(File f3 : dirlist)
{
        if(f3.getName().endsWith(".wav"))
        {
           String firstnam = f3.getName();
           String secondnam = firstnam.replaceFirst(".wav", "_converted.wav")
           String[] command = {"cmd", "/c", "AdpcmEncode.exe", firstnam, secondnam};
           Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();       
           Process process = rt.exec(command, null, dir);
        }

}
```

What I need most is to know how to pass these dynamic parameters into the command, if it's posible also know how to change names through audio conversions (the input and output can't be the same).

Comment: You may also consider using a [FileFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) for your `listFiles(fileFilter)` invocation and avoid having to define the `if` clause yourself.

Comment: `replaceFirst` takes a regular expression. `.` in regular expressions means "match anything". Try `"\\.wav"` instead. Also consider attempting to debug into your script to see what is actually going wrong. Because "it just doesn't work" is not very descriptive.

Comment: Thanks, I've didn't notice that because I'm a beginner on java, only remains to know how to make the dynamic parameters work

Comment: Try using  `ProcessBuilder("AdpcmEncode.exe",firstname,secondnam).start()`. You are also missing a semicolon at `replaceFirst`.

Comment: ProcessBuilder makes the .exe appear on the screen, thing that I don't want in my program.

Comment: I actually did the debug and nothing is showing up, maybe because I'm making an interface script intead of working on console.

Comment: Please answer the main cuestion, I already have an idea to do the loop, I just want to make parameters work.

Answer (score 0):

Well after a research about this, I have finally put my code in a separate class from the main JFrame (That fixed the dynamic parameters, for some reason I don't understand, I have to say that code I had it into another JFrame Class), now because the code is into an IOException, the thing was a little bit complicated, but I realize that it was simple like this:

```
    try{
    ConvertAllClass.converter(null);
    }catch(IOException e){
     //e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Maybe the null is not necessary, but all works. This is the "test" function (I just wanted to know if converts one audio at least):

```
public class ConvertAllClass {



public static void converter(String args[]) throws IOException {

File f = new File("C:\\convertion_kit\\bin");
String firstnam = "mx_game_over.wav";
String secondnam = "mx_done.wav";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c","start","AdpcmEncode.exe", firstnam, secondnam );
pb.directory(f);
Process process = pb.start();


}
}
```